# std::future in c++ with raspberry e sysroot

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, raspberry-pi, visualgdb

I'm writing a sample code to learn the asynchronos function with std::async.

My code it's very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

void error(char *msg)
{
    std::cout << msg;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::future<void> asyncr = std::async(errore,"start async");

    std::cout << "finish";
}
```

i think this is all correct, but my VisualStudio with VisualGDB throw an error in "asyncr":

> [Clang IntelliSense] Error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::future'

I lost several hours, and i want to find a solution.

I will be very grateful to those who will help me

Comment: `std::future` is a C++11 feature, so you need to check whether the compiler supports it and if you are passing the correct flags to enabled C++11 (if required)

Comment: CFLAG: -ggdb -ffunction-sections
CXXFLAG: -std=gnu++14 -ggdb -ffunction-sections -O0 -lpthread

Comment: This isn't the problem, but to ensure that text is displayed on the console it should end with a newline character (`'\n'`): `std::cout << "finish\n";`. For the call to `std::async` you can either add the newline to the text that you pass in (`"start async\n"`) or you can add it explicitly in the output line: `std::cout << msg << '\n';`.

Comment: is not a problem how the text is displayed @PeteBecker

Comment: @ManuelePerrone Could you add a full error message? Because without typos all works.

Comment: @ManuelePerrone How did you solve the problem?